# Resizeing the layout zones

Tags: page-layout, web-part-zone

I am using a 2-1 formation on my main site. i want one of the bottom zones to become thinner while the other one becomes wider.

Tip Tip

Comment: Share some snap with layout you want to have. Your question is not able to explain what you are asking exactly. Clear the question please.

Comment: @PradipR. never mind.